# How can I count the Mongo records that match a query or See if there are any results to a query?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

## Nutshell:

I want to see if my Days Mongo collection contains any JavaScript Date() objects from today.

```
var start = new Date().setHours(0,0,0);
var end = new Date().setHours(23,59,59);
var x = Days.find({time: {$gte: start, $lt: end}}).count(); // always returns 0.
console.log(x);
```

I can see the results in the console, but don't know how to extract what I need to make a conditional based on the results.

## More info: Punch in once per day

I'm making a very basic app that tracks a time you punch in **once** each day (and highlights the ones that you do before a standard goal time you set).

It's basically a simpler http://5clubapp.com, that lets you set the time.

The database is very basic: A collection of *days*

```
Days = new Mongo.Collection("days");
```

... each one having a JavaScript Date() object: `time: Date()`.

#### I call the punchIn function in Meteor:

```
punchIn: function () {
  var start = new Date().setHours(0,0,0);
  var end = new Date().setHours(23,59,59);
  var x = Days.find({time: {$gte: start, $lt: end}}).count();

  if (x == 0) {
      // Punch in
      Days.insert({
        time: new Date() // current time
      });

  } else {
      // You already punched in today
  }
```

I'm enjoying Meteor so far, but I'm entirely new to Mongo. The answer could be insanely easy, but what I've tried hasn't worked, so I'm turning to you.

This is just a test project to help me get acquainted with Meteor & Mongo, so I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible. (If I have time, I'll add stuff later - users, customizable goals... maybe even charts!)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `new Date().setHours(0,0,0)` it creates a new `Date` object and then runs `setHours` which does what you want, but it **returns** the integer representation of the date, which is what you end up storing in `start`. You need to do this:

```
var start = new Date();
start.setHours(0,0,0);

var end = new Date();
end.setHours(23,59,59);
```

If you are going to do a lot of date manipulation, I'd recommend using a library like [moment](https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/moment). I'd also recommend that `punchIn` be a method (unclear from your question) so that the same clock (the server's) is used to record all of the dates.

Comment: I was about to post just that!  Alternatively you could do `new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0))`.  You're usually shielded from this as JS does the necessary casting for you, but Mongo does not.

Comment: You know, that's how I originally wrote it.
Then I thought I'd get clever and save two lines.
*facepalm*

It's always the little things...